# Adding a new contact with a birthday doesn't add birthday event

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm adding a new contact to my Office365 account using the C# SDK of Microsoft Graph and the following code:

```cs
var contact = new Contact
{
    ...
    Birthday = new DateTimeOffset(1988, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, offset: TimeSpan.Zero)
};
await graphServiceClient.Me.Contacts.Request().AddAsync(contact);
```

I can verify that a new contact has been created with the given birthday e.g. by querying this exact contact using the Microsoft Graph API.

Adding a contact that has its birthday set should create me a new event in the birthday calendar (and I'm pretty sure that it used to work some months ago).
However the birthday calendar doesn't show the birthday event. When I'm then updating the contact's birthday by hand using the web portal it suddenly creates the birthday event.

Why isn't the birthday event automatically added to the birthday calendar when I add a new contact using the Graph API?

Comment: I'm going to reach out to our devs on this one to get a definitive answer, but I'd be surprised if the design was to create a birthday event. That could be seen as an unintended side effect of creating a contact, and apps that don't have the Calendar.ReadWrite permission shouldn't be able to create events! :)

Comment: I appreciate that, thanks a lot. The birthday calendar is read-only, so I can't explicitly create an event. But I could imagine that the app just needs `Calendar.ReadWrite` permission, I'll check that.

Comment: Ok, my app already *had* `Calendar.ReadWrite` permission, so that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting that was the problem, I was just pointing out that creating a contact and creating an event are two separately managed permissions, so tying the two actions together wouldn't make a whole lot of sense (at least in my mind). I'm still waiting for an answer on how this should work though.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so the question then is: How can I create a birthday event given that the calendar itself is read-only (at least the API says so). I'll edit my question.

Comment: Scratch that.
I see the birthday calendar as a *view at the contacts*. So it's not a stand-alone calendar where you can add events to but it's an *automatically* updated calendar that keeps *in sync* with your contacts. So I wouldn't even expect needing any `Calendar` permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it again today and it seems to work now. I didn't update anything, I didn't change any code, so I guess Microsoft fixed that on their servers. Thanks.